# word doc from sql server 2008 to jsp

Tags: sql-server-2008, jsp, parsing

How  best i can store a word doc in sql server 2008 and retrieving in HTML format to show it in a JSP FILE

the html file should not loose the Rich text format and images.

Regards
prasad

Answer (score 0):

Although not quite raw HTML output, this can be done using the Google Docs viewer in an embedded iframe and can be accomplished in two steps. You will need to first create a Servlet or JAX-RS which will provide the document as a resource. There are many examples on how to do this, but you might want to start [here](http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/enterprise-java/rest/jax-rs-download-file/). Then you can write your JSP with a simple iframe using the Google Doc's viewer URI which references your resource URI:

```
<iframe src=""http://docs.google.com/gview?embedded=true&url=http://your.document/resource"></iframe>
```

The end result is quite useful as it contains many standard Google Docs features. [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/3sPQk/1/) is also a sample of what the iframe will display.